# Writing a File In a Sibling Directory using Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In Rust, how do you write to a new file that is in a sibling directory of `main.rs`?

```
<my_project_root>
├── src
│  └── main.rs
├── output
│  └── hello.txt
```

Tried using `../` but am getting a error about no such file or directory.

```
use std::fs;
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let filename = "hello.txt";
    let filepath = format!("../output/{}", filename);
    let data: [u8; 32] = thread_rng().gen();
    fs::write(filepath, data).expect("Unable to write file");
}
```

Error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to write file: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:8:31

Comment: The current working directory has nothing to do with where `main.rs` is located and everything to do with where you run the code from. How are you invoking this program?

Comment: paths are typically relative to where the program is run, if you're running the program from the project root, the path would be `"output/{}"`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm running `cargo run --release` in the parent directory of `main.rs`. Thanks, I see the problem now :)

Comment: Is it possible to get the path of `main.rs` and use it to derive the path of the sibling directory? This way, it will not matter where i am running the program from

Comment: It is entirely possible to run the binary on an entirely different machine that the one it was compiled on, so it is utterly unreasonable to depend on paths relative to the source files.